# Node.js equivalent program for below PHP snippet

Tags: php, node.js

Can anyone suggest how to write Node.js equivalent program with crypto module for below PHP snippet

```
$source = ...;
$secretKey = pack('H*', "SECRET_KEY");
$decoded = base64_decode($source);
$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $secretKey, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

Comment: Try looking into using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rijndael

Answer (score 0):

This example is taken from https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rijndael

```
// Import module
var rijndael = require('./examples/rijndael');

// Set key
var key = new Buffer('theonetruesecretkeytorulethemall', 'utf-8').toString('base64');
var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');


// Encrypt message
var plaintext = 'hello, world!';
var ciphertext = rijndael.encrypt(plaintext, key, iv);

// 'hello, world!' encodes to
// '50yvJtooiLHUOAbniGgMHmZE18Op99Rhe+Y+G6AjPzM='


// Decrypt message
var decryptedMessage = rijndael.decrypt(ciphertext, key, iv);

// '50yvJtooiLHUOAbniGgMHmZE18Op99Rhe+Y+G6AjPzM=' decodes to
// 'hello, world!'
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, but I got a different npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/mcrypt and it  worked :-).

Comment: Good and no worries :)

Comment: var MCrypt = require('mcrypt').MCrypt;  

var aesEcb = new MCrypt('rijndael-128', 'ecb');  
aesEcb.open(new Buffer(SECRET_KEY, 'hex'));  

var ciphertext = new Buffer(input, 'base64');  
var plaintext = aesEcb.decrypt(SOURCE).toString('utf8');  

//console.log(plaintext);